# How can I reference a nested yaml to a Jinja template output?

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml to append variables into my output yaml.

```
def fixupYaml(tgt_sw,bgp,loopback):
    loopback = ''.join(map(str,loopback))
    loopfinal = re.sub(r"[\([{''})\]]", "", loopback)
    bgpid = loopfinal[:-3]
    bgp = list(map(int,bgp))
    print (loopfinal,bgp)
    file = 'device.yaml'
    config, ind, bsi = ruamel.yaml.util.load_yaml_guess_indent(open(file))
    data = config['data']
    data[0]['name'] = tgt_sw
    data[0]['BGPASN'] = bgp
    data[0]['l15pass'] = 'test'
    data[0]['l0'] = loopfinal
    data[0]['bgpid'] = bgpid
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.indent(mapping=ind, sequence=ind, offset=bsi) 
    with open('output.yaml', 'w') as fp:
        yaml.dump(config, fp)
```

my output.yaml like this after the above has been ran.

```
data:
    - name: testSpinepoap01
      BGPASN:
          - 65000
      l15pass: test
      l0: 10.224.32.240/32
      bgpid: 10.224.32.240
      DNSP: 10.245.129.105
      DNSS: 10.246.129.105
      NTPP: 10.250.10.10
      NTPS: 10.251.10.10
      acastm: 239.255.128.0/24
      acastu: 10.224.128.0
      mgmtGW: 10.0.0.1/32
```

my issue is when I go to merge the output.yaml with my merged.txt file none of the variables show up its just blank space where the variable should be. I suspect that's because I'm nested inside data:

little context to the below, templete.txt is the baseline config svi is a rest call from an onprim application we use. I merge those two together then use the for mentioned output.yaml file to update merged.txt config to create the final config.

```
def mergeTxt(swSN):
    filenames = ['template.txt','svi.txt']
    with open('merged.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for names in filenames:
            with open(names) as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
            outfile.write("\n")
    config = yaml.safe_load(open('output.yaml'))
    env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader('./'), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
    template = env.get_template('merged.txt')
    targetconfig = (template.render(config))
```

sample merged.txt

```
hostname {{data.name}}
!
!
! 
feature nxapi
feature bash-shell
feature tacacs+
feature bgp
feature pim
feature bfd
!
!
!
!
clock timezone CST -6 0
clock summer-time CDT 2 Sun Mar 02:00 1 Sun Nov 02:00 60
username admin password {{l15pass}}  role network-admin
```

Is it possible to utilize jinja templates with a nested yaml ? if not is it possible to append to a yaml without ruamel? Any help is appreciated im pretty stuck right now not sure what to do without rebuilding everything to no include ruamel as its seems nesting is required.

Comment: I don't know much about jinja2, but you are using `{{data.name}}` and the root level key `data` in your YAML doesn't have a key `name` in its value because the value for key `data` is a sequence/list. You either have to tell jinja2 which sequence element to use or make the value of `data` a mapping/dict.

Comment: so maybe im not grasping that root level key but im doing data.name ect to refer to root key then sub key name. So based of what your saying I shouldn't need .name if that's the case how would i reference .name in my template ?

Comment: No idea how you index a sequence/list in jinja2. You should ask yourself why you create it in the first place if you don't want to use it.